# log4net configuration exception

Tags: logging, web-config, log4net, configsection

I am using log4net for logging. My logging configuration is stored in a separate file.

Web.Config:ConfigSections

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

Specifying my config file in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

And when I initialize my LogManager, I get this error

```
"System.TypeLoadException"
message: Could not load type 'log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHlandler' from assembly 'Log4net'.
```

Yes it says "Log4NetConfigurationSectionHlandler'", it is not a typo

and later, this error

```
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for log4net: Could not load type 'log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHlandler' from assembly 'Log4net'.
```

Edit: Tried Mauricio Scheffer's suggestion

got

```
log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321261/configuring-log4net-with-xml-file

Comment: Edit:I just found that my web.config had a type "Log4NetConfigurationSectionHlandler" was from web.config. I am still working on getting this work with an external config file

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you have your config in a separate log4net.config file you don't need the sectionHandler. Remove it.

You're also probably calling [XmlConfigurator.Configure()](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_1.html) somewhere in your code. Remove that as well.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321261/configuring-log4net-with-xml-file)

Comment: I second this response.  I was getting the same problem in my WPF application when I had the log4net section in my `app.config` file.  I moved the config to a separate log4net.config file and it resolved the issue.

Comment: I got this error on trying this suggestion:

log4net:ERROR XmlConfigurator: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />

Comment: @ram: you're probably calling XmlConfigurator.Configure() somewhere in your code. remove that.

Comment: I am a bit lost mauricio, I am calling it when I initialize my Log Manager
static ActivityLogManager()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        }

It should not be called ?

Comment: OK now I get it, since my config file is external, I should not call XMLConfigurator.Configure as it is looking for the config section in my web/app.config. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Exactly, you should *not* call it. The assembly attribute already handles the initialization.

Comment: Hey Mauricio, should the external config file be ".xml" or can it have ".config" extension ?

Comment: @ram doesn't matter, it can be anything.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio. Am working on it, will update this post ASAP

Comment: Thanks Mauricio it worked. Am posting one new question soon. Its about using one class in am assembly to log all events and I see that "logger" is getting set to this static logging class and not the class which is calling this Log methods

Comment: @Darren : logging configuration should **never** be defined in *libraries*. It's the responsibility of the *application*.

Comment: @Darren : it does work without adding anything to the libraries. Your issue is likely elsewhere. Please ask a new question with all relevant details.

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185726/how-to-use-log4net-in-asp-net-from-multiple-assemblies