# Log4Net Error: Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file

Tags: c#, config, log4net, class-library

I currently use a class library to store a class that handles logging using log4net. This class is used in other projects.

I've read a lot of other questions and answers, but I haven't been able to fix it yet...

I enabled internal debugging of log4net because it would not write to a file, and this is the error I get:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's .config file. Check your .config file for the <log4net> and <configSections> elements. The configuration section should look like: <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
```

These are my files:
*log4net.config*

```
<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="Logs/log4net.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

*App.config*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
      </configSections>

      <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>

      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@BlogId" />
        <dbType value="Int32" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
          <key value="BlogId" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </configuration>
```

*AssemblyInfo.cs* (just last line)

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

*Logger.cs*

```
public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public Logger()
        {
            XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            logger.Info("NEW LOGGER INSTANCE CREATED");
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I fixed it by letting the class that uses my Logger.cs give its own .config file for log4net. Now log4net reads the given .config files and it works.

Comment: Related post - [Configuring log4net with xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1321261/465053)

Comment: Correct additionally: `value="[Header]&#13;&#10;"` and  `value="[Footer]&#13;&#10;"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have defined that the log4net section is in your app.config with:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
```

that means you should add the content of the log4net.config to the app.config file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to **implement a wrapper over log4net** where the log4net lives **in its own class library** and **not** in the main executable of your application, try something like this in a static constructor of your wrapper class:

```
static Logger()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo
                                            (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName

    (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)));
}
```

The static constructor solution ensures that if you load the class library, the configuration code will run.

You will also need to do something to copy the **log4net.config file** from that class library project into the same folder as the executable. You can do this by hand when deploying the application; however, to do it automatically when debugging a post-build step with something like this (from the class library project) will put the config file into the right folder:

```
XCOPY "$(TargetDir)*.config" ".\..\..\..\..\bin\Debug" /S /Y /I
XCOPY "$(TargetDir)*.config" ".\..\..\..\..\bin\Release" /S /Y /I

// Where those paths point to the main executable /bin folders 
// and build configuration target dirs
```

A good reason to use this approach is that if you're leveraging something like MEF, you can bring in your logger wrapper class as an **interface** and you don't need to reference log4net in more than one project in your solution. You can interface with the logger with an *abstract interface* of your own choosing, and use log4net as the Impl. (Bridge pattern)

Good luck!

Comment: Hello! Chad, would you please elaborate on what code of the static constructor does exactly?  My .sln contains 3 projects. (1) Windows.Service, (2) ASP.NET app and (3) shared Class - wrapper for log4net. (1) gets installed in a separate directory and (2) in its own. Where the app gonna look for the .config? Looking forward to read from you

Comment: bad practice to use `xcopy`, use in csproj `<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="log4net.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>`

Answer (score 1):

When I migrated a solution from .NET Framework to .NET6.0 I had the same error.
I noticed I had a two different configs files:

1. App.config (only with startup section and supportedRuntime property)
2. log4net.config (only with 2 appenders to Console and external file)

**Solution:** The whole trick was to copy code from log4net.config and paste it to the App.config under configuration section and define configSection with log4net.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <DUMMY_DATA>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <DUMMY_DATA>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```