# How to convert text logs to html logs in c#?

Tags: c#, html, log4net

I am getting formatted .txt logs through log4net ,but not able to insert new line in html format, So I want to convert it to html log file so that, I can get a formatted html file and also insert screenshots to that html log file. so I want to know how to convert the .txt log file to .html log file using c# .

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1147774/69809) what you need?

Answer (score 0):

How are you configuring log4net - programmatically or via a config file. Have you considered using new line tag?

```
> <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
>         <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" /> </layout
```

Comment: this "%newline" is not working for .html file .