# Write raw text in log file using log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I have create the custom xml layout using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147774/4427808). i need log  message with character `<` but in log file it converted to `&lt;` this is my code sample

```
public class MyXmlLayout : XmlLayoutBase
{
    protected override void FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("LogEntry");
        writer.WriteStartElement("Exception");
        writer.WriteString("<![CDATA[\n" + loggingEvent.GetExceptionString() + "\n]]>");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Output log file

```
<LogEntry>
    <Exception>&lt;![CDATA[
        System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
           at ConsoleApplication5.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\MahendranM\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication5\ConsoleApplication5\Program.cs:line 24
        ]]&gt;
    </Exception>
</LogEntry>
```

How can print raw character like `<,>`in log4net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, you could use

```
writer.WriteRaw("<![CDATA[\n" + loggingEvent.GetExceptionString() + "\n]]>");
```

or

```
writer.WriteCData(loggingEvent.GetExceptionString());
```

However, I would *strongly* discourage you from doing this. There's no guarantee that you'll end up with valid XML at the end... if your text contains `"]]>"` then it will cause problems. (With `WriteRaw` you'll end up with invalid XML; with `WriteCData` you'll end up with an exception.)

I would expect the purpose of using an XML log file to be simply to propagate the data for each log entry, in an XML format. So just use `writer.WriteString(loggingEvent.GetExceptionString())` and then whatever *reads* the log file later can do the right thing with it. Wrapping it in CData rather than letting the XML API just escape it as it needs to seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: using CData is bad idea but default log4net just doing the same when it write the long exception message.

Comment: @Mahendran: That doesn't mean you have to do so though... (And if it *does* use CData, hopefully it's taking care of the `]]>` issue...)

Comment: using writer.WriteCData leads to exception when text contain `]]>`.