# Log4Net Layout.XmlLayout does not create logs in .NET Core platform

Tags: c#, .net-core, log4net

I have implemented logger for my application and I wanted to log the activity in XML format (XmlLayout) on .NET Core Console Application.
The Log4Net configuration includes FileAppender and XmlFileAppender as follows.

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Log4NetLogs\UaGatewayText.log.txt"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="[%date{dd.MM.yyyy}] [%date{ABSOLUTE}] [%thread] 
     %level %property{TEST - Ua.Gateway} %message%newline" />

     </layout>
        </appender>
           <appender name="ConsolAppender" 
                            type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%dae{DATE}] [%date{ABSOLUTE}] [%thread] 
                  [%level] %message%newline" />
      </layout>
   </appender>


    <appender name="XmlFileAppender" 
               type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
           <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
                value="C:\Log4NetLogs\UaGatewayXml.log.xml" />
        <appendToFile value= "true" />
        <rollingStyle value="size"/>
        <maximumFileSize value ="50MB"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value ="10"/>
       <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout" />
    </appender>


   <root>
     <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="XmlFileAppender" />

   </root>

 </log4net>
```

In .NET Core Console App, XmlAppender creates  UaGatewayXml.log.xml file in the directory and does not write any log. However, it works great with FileAppender.

The above configuration works as expected for .NET Framework (4.5.*) for both XmlFileAppender and FileAppender.

Do I have to make any change in the Config file?
Thanks

Comment: Have you [had a look at the log4net debug output](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)?

Comment: I saw it earlier. .NET Core project does not contain App.config file so I cannot do it.

Comment: That's only one way to enable debugging - you can also use `<log4net debug="true">` in your log4net config, or you can do it in code with `log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is with `log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j` it uses method `writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:event");` which causes validation error.

You can create your own layout (take code from here [here](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4net/blob/f5fdf89fdfb27ea76a500f962690b14eafadcac2/src/Layout/XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j.cs) )

and just change

```
writer.WriteStartElement("log4j:event")
```

into

```
writer.WriteStartElement("log4j", "event", "log4j");
```

This method that takes the prefix, element name, and namespace.
I have opened the output *XML* file in *YALV* and everything works fine. 
Don't forget to correct all `WriteStartElement` methods.

I have written this solution [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-586).

Comment: Thanks! To elaborate a bit on this solution: i.e. you can put this file somewhere into your own asp.net assembly: https://pastebin.com/5rKNDPXf
and then reference it in the log4net config using what's described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147103/log4net-xml-output#comment966132_1147774

Comment: Uh.. I had a typo in that pastebin, here's the fixed one: https://pastebin.com/JpN6tc48

Comment: I share the file from onedrive:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgcSwFZhZyF0iQGp4co6u9OO4F-5

also don't forget to add 

`<layout type="MyNamespace.Extensions.log4net.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4jExt, MyAssembly">`

Comment: Works for me. Just add the line <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j, QConnectServer"> in the log4netConfig

Answer (score 1):

load the config manually:

```
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

Comment: var collection = XmlConfigurator.Configure(_LoggerRepository, new FileInfo(_Log4netConfigPath));

Comment: As I already explained in the problem I am facing that my logger works for Pattern Layout for .txt file. But I guess theres is some problem with following in .NET Core Framework
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayout" />

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with an ASP.Net Core 2.0 web application.

I enabled internal debugging and saw the following:

*log4net:ERROR [RollingFileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Failed in DoAppend
System.ArgumentException: Invalid name character in 'log4j:event'. The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.CheckNCName(String ncname)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteStartElement(String prefix, String localName, String ns)
   at log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j.FormatXml(XmlWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutBase.Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.FileAppender.Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)*

I replaced

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
```

with

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout"> 
  <conversionPattern value="%date{yyyyMMddHHmmss.fff} [%thread] %-5level %logger %appdomain - %class - %exception - %method - %property{GlobalLog4NetProperty} - %property{ThreadProperty} - %property{log4net:HostName} - %message%newline"/>
</layout>
```